# url_launcher#launchUrl() returns false on chrome and edge in flutter web project

Tags: flutter, web, url-launcher

Tested in debug and in production on Chrome and Edge.

[My flutter web project](https://portfolio.peterolson.dev) throws an `Exception` after I click the code (`< >`) `IconButton` in the upper-right corner. You may be able to confirm in your devtools console. The `Exception` should only be thrown if `url_launcher` **fails** to launch the url... but the new tab opens just fine.

This is how I'm calling `url_launcher#launchUrl()`

```
Future<void> _launchUrl(String urlString) async {
  if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(urlString))) {
    throw Exception("Could not launch $urlString");
  }
}
```

This method is called from the `AppBar` actions

```
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
  title: Text(widget.title),
  actions: [
    IconButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {
      _launchUrl("https://gitlab.com/friend.code");
    }), icon: const Icon(Icons.code)),
    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.music_note))
  ],
),
```

This is ~exactly as written in the [url_launcher example](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/example).

I was able to debug the `url_launcher#launchUrl()` execution up to `url_launcher_web#openNewWindow()`, which calls `_window.open(url, target, 'noopener, noreferrer');`. I am unable to step into that method, so not sure what is happening there, but this method call returns `null`.

Why am I getting a seemingly false-negative result here?

[Full source code](https://gitlab.com/portfolio7194346/ui/-/blob/ec6b2a9f8b0651e734bb2c04465e0b7a0f9d4a40/lib/main.dart)

## webOnlyWindowName

If I set `webOnlyWindowName: "_self"`, then the link opens in the current tab and I do not see any console error. If I set `webOnlyWindowName: "_blank"`, then I still get the console error **even though the new tab opens as intended.** The [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html) say that `launchUrl` "**Returns true if the URL was launched successful**, otherwise either returns false or throws a PlatformException depending on the failure." I just want to know why it's returning false.

## created GitHub issue

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/139783

Comment: I'm getting the same problem now that I have updated to Flutter 3.16.3 and url_launcher 6.2.1. On Chrome, Brave, Firefox, etc. Did you create [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+url_launcher%22) at Flutter?

Comment: I just created an issue and pasted the link above. Thanks for confirming it is at least reproducible. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have used

```
kIsWeb?html.window.open(
  "https://gitlab.com/friend.code",
  "GitLab",
): _launchUrl("https://gitlab.com/friend.code");
```

or

```
 await launchUrl(
      Uri.parse(url),
      webOnlyWindowName: isNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self',
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @PradeepKumar, I have updated my post. `launchUrl` is still returning false even though the new tab opens as intended.